# Scala - implicit evidence of list of tuples of lists

Tags: scala, implicit

I am having difficulty making the implicit requirements of `flatUnzip` work properly.  Currently it seems the first requirement that `A` is a `Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]` is being ignored (and hence the sanity check fails to compile).  Any suggestions here?  When answering, please also explain what is wrong with my current attempt.

```
  class MySeq[A](val _seq: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def flatUnzip[T1, T2, CC1[T1], CC2[T2]](
      implicit ev1: A =:= Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]],
      ev2: CC1[T1] <:< TraversableOnce[T1],
      ev3: CC2[T2] <:< TraversableOnce[T2],
      cbf1: CanBuildFrom[CC1[T1], T1, CC1[T1]],
      cbf2: CanBuildFrom[CC2[T2], T2, CC2[T2]]
    ): (CC1[T1], CC2[T2]) = {
      val foo: Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]] = _seq // sanity check fails
      val list1 = cbf1()
      val list2 = cbf2()
      for ((xs, ys) <- _seq) {
        list1 ++= xs
        list2 ++= ys
      }
      return (list1.result, list2.result)
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

I found that the following works, but only when the `=:=` is applied in the direction as shown:

```
  class MySeq[A](val _seq: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def mapBy[B](func: A => B): Map[B, A] = _seq.map(x => (func(x), x)).toMap
    def flatUnzip[T1, T2, CC1[T1], CC2[T2]](
      implicit
      ev1: Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]] =:= A,
      ev2: Seq[A] =:= Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]],
      ev3: CC1[T1] <:< TraversableOnce[T1],
      ev4: CC2[T2] <:< TraversableOnce[T2],
      cbf1: CanBuildFrom[CC1[T1], T1, CC1[T1]],
      cbf2: CanBuildFrom[CC2[T2], T2, CC2[T2]]
    ): (CC1[T1], CC2[T2]) = {
      val list1 = cbf1()
      val list2 = cbf2()
      for ((xs, ys) <- _seq: Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]]) {
        list1 ++= xs
        list2 ++= ys
      }
      return (list1.result, list2.result)
    }
  }
```

However, replacing `Seq[A] =:= Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]]` with `Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]] =:= Seq[A]` or `Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]] =:= A`  with `A =:= Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]` causes problems.  Can someone please explain why the order here matters, and why each of these `A =:= B` relationships is needed to make this work?

Comment: nitpick: you don't need `return` here

Comment: nitpick #2: `[T1, T2, CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]` doesn't mean what you think it means. You can just write `[T1, T2, CC1[_], CC2[_]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by changing the `ev1` to:

```
implicit ev1: Seq[A] =:= Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]],
```

Just because you have evidence that `A` is `=:=` some type, doesn't mean that evidence works for `Seq[A]`, too. So ask directly for the evidence you actually need.

You'll also need to change the `for` comprehension to:

```
for ((xs, ys) <- _seq: Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]]) {
```

without the typecast to trigger a search, the compiler won't go looking for `ev1`.

**UPDATE:**

As you point out in your edited question, those fixes aren't enough to make the code work. You found the additional fixes needed yourself, but why do they work?

It's because the evidence supplied by `=:=` isn't just a dummy value that is ignored. `=:=` extends `Function1`, and what it does the function do? It converts from the type on the left to the type on the right. At runtime, it does nothing (it's an identity function); but at compile time, the function may need to be applied in order to convert the type on the left to the type on the right.

In your revised code, `ev2` is used on the input, to convert `_seq` to the right type. If you compile the code with `-Xprint:typer`, you will see the explicit calls to `ev2`, `ev3`, and `ev4`.

Oh, uh, what about `ev1`? I'm not sure. That doesn't show up in the compiled code. I'm not seeing right now why it's needed. The compiler seems to need it as a stepping stone in order to derive `ev2`.

**UPDATE #2:**

Aha! For `ev2`, use `<:<`, not `=:=`. Then you don't need `ev1` anymore.

Comment: This still seems to cause problems.  When I run it on `new MySeq(List(
(List(1,2,3),List(11,12,13)),
(List(4,5,6),List(14,15,16)),
(List(7,8,9),List(17,18,19))
)).flatUnzip` it says `Cannot prove that Seq[(List[Int], List[Int])] =:= Seq[(CC1[T1], CC2[T2])]`

Comment: Why would `ev1` need to be used on the output?  The output is of type `(CC1[T1], CC2[T2])`, which is not defined w.r.t. `A`

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I don't know why `ev1` is needed. `-Xprint:typer` gives no clue. I've edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: It seems I can replace the current `ev1` with `Seq[Tuple2[CC1[T1], CC2[T2]]] =:= Seq[A]` and it still works.  In other words, I need to specify =:= in both directions as 2 different pieces of evidence.  Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure I understand everything going on here, but see update #2.